# Find Missing Data in Excel Column

Tags: excel, compare

I'm using Excel 2003 and am trying to compare two columns to find data in one column that is not in the other column.

For example:

[image]

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998547/compare-two-columns-in-excel

Comment: Hiten004's suggestion/link will work, or you can also Vlookup Column A values with Column B as the lookup array, and follow the "#n/a"s

Answer (score 0):

in VBA, you can try the following ugly but working code:

```
Sub missing()

Dim ya As Long, yb As Long, yc As Long, alast As Long, blast As Long
Dim flag As Boolean

yc = 2
yb = 2
flag = 0
alast = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
blast = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

For ya = 2 To alast
flag = 0

Do While yb <= blast
    If Range("A" & ya) = Range("B" & yb) Then flag = 1
    yb = yb + 1
    Loop

    If flag = 0 Then
        Range("C" & yc) = Range("A" & ya)
        yc = yc + 1
    End If

    yb = 2

Next ya

End Sub
```